Telegram Mini App: Wallet Connect AppKit Wallet redirection issue on first time click in iphone. Demo app works fine there is loaders
I'm building the Telegram mini app with AppKit and following the React example with Ethers.
When the wallet modal opens, none of the wallets appear ready. In the demo Telegram mini app (available here), a loader is displayed next to the wallet list for 3-5 seconds while the wallets are loading.

However, in my app, no loaders are visible. If users click a wallet before it's ready, the redirection fails. Clicking after 5 seconds works fine.
Note: This issue occurs only on the first load.
Note: this issue getting first time only and on Iphone only
Packages I'm Using:

@reown/appkit: "^1.5.0"
@reown/appkit-adapter-ethers: "^1.5.0"
@walletconnect/modal-core: "^2.7.0"
@walletconnect/modal-ui: "^2.7.0"
ethers: "^6.13.4"

- react app AppKit intialize
  createAppKit(newConfig);
       
  const newConfig: any = {
    adapters: [ethersAdapter],
    networks,
    metadata,
    projectId,
    features: {
      analytics: true,
      email: false,
      onramp: false,
      socials: [],
    },
    // defaultNetwork: mainnetChain,
  };

AppKit Component:
<appkit-button />  
